# Angular Material Slider - issue with setting value to zero

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular5

I want to create a slider using Angular Materials and Angular 5 that when the value is set to 0 on the slider then it will move back up to 10.

I am having an issue where the slider will not move back up to 10 if it was already at 10, otherwise it will.

myComponent.html

```
<mat-slider [(ngModel)]="weight" (change)="change()"></mat-slider>
```

myComponent.ts

```
  weight = 50;

  change(){
    if(this.weight == 0){
      this.weight = 10;
    }
  }
```

I have recreated the issue in StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whq8ll

Comment: The demo is working as expected. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Faisal  Not exactly:)

Comment: Yeah, now I see what the problem is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is occurring because the `change()` is setting the value of the item outside the scope of the event changes. One way to solve this is to include the `change()` in the scope of change detection with `ChangeDetectorRef`. The other way would be to directly set the slide value to proc the change event again:

**Component side :**

```
weight = 50;
@ViewChild('slider')slider;
change(){
    console.log(this.slider.value);
    if(this.weight == 0){
    this.slider.value = 10;
    }
}
```

**Template side :**

```
<mat-slider [(ngModel)]="weight" #slider (change)="change()"></mat-slider>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-set-slider)**